# Create audiobook from mp3 files?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, mp3

How do I transfer a folder containing mp3 files to my iPod/iTunes to be recognized as an audiobook?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use iTunes 10 in Windows 7.

1. Select the tracks.
2. Right-click and select **Get Info**.
3. Open the **Options** tab.
4. Set:
   Equilizer Preset = Spoken Word
   Media Kind = Audiobook
   Part of a compilation = No
   Remember position = Yes
   Skip when shuffling = Yes
   Gapless album = No
5. Press **OK**.

Also, make sure the correct track numbers and disc numbers are set for each track.

Comment: What do "Part of a compilation" and "Gapless album" mean?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure.  I think a compelation is like an album where every song is by a different artist (eg. *The Best Hits of 2000*).  A gapless album might be where the tracks are mixed together so there's no silence throughout the album, like many dance music albums.  I don't know how they affect iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

I used to do the method that Hand-E-Food used. It works fine, but you still end up with a ton of individual mp3 files. This was a pain for me because of the way they showed up when I plug them into my car stereo.

After a bunch of looking around, I found [AudioBook Builder](http://www.splasm.com/audiobookbuilder/). It takes all the mp3 files and converts them into a single .m4b audiobook file. Assuming you are on a Mac, it's worth a look.

The app is available directly in the App Store. I've only used it a few times, but that's only because I don't have that many audio books. It was quick and easy and more than worth the price for the hassle it saved me.